# blockUI works but error on 2nd time calling it

Tags: jquery, typeerror, blockui

I've got a strange thing with this blockUI plugin.

This is the function i made to call the block:

```
function runBlockUI(selector,width)
{
    $.blockUI({ 
        message: $(selector),
        centerY: 0, 
        css: { 
            top:  '30px', 
            left: ($(window).width() - width) /2 + 'px', 
            width: width + 'px',
            height: '550px'}
    });
    $('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Klik om venster te sluiten');
    $('.blockOverlay').click($.unblockUI);
}
```

The thing is the function is being called by 3 different selectors. With 2 it works perfectly. But with the other its only working once. After closing and recalling the function i get the following error (In firebug):

```
TypeError: $.blockUI is not a function
```

I'm pretty confused about this and hope someone can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Grtz

**!!!SOLVED!!!**

The problem is sovled. I'm so dumb that I didn't saw this lol. The function works good on 2 items. But with the one which is not working the message div contains a load() function of an html file. I was so stupid to use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

in the loaded html. This load did "unset" the blockUI plugin. Removed the js include and it's working now! Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Could you add your code, where the call fails?

Comment: The problem is sovled. I'm so dumb that I didn't saw this lol. The function works good on 2 items. But with the one which is not working the message div contains a load() function of an html file. I was so stupid to use <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> in the loaded html. This load did "unset" the blockUI plugin. Removed the js include and it's working now! Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Look's like this line is the problem..

```
$('.blockOverlay').click($.unblockUI);
```

You are assigning a method to the click event rather than a function..

```
$('.blockOverlay').click(function() {$.unblockUI() } ); // Supposed to be called this way
```

Also you are assigning the click event every single time you are calling the function.. 
Move this line out of the function call..

Comment: It should be `$('.blockOverlay').click(function() { $.unblockUI() } );`, also I think that the original assignment is correct.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this all!! I've found out what caused the problem! See my comment below the OP.